# Clase Point (Manipular el puntero con coordenadas eje (x,y) JAVA)

Tags: java

Se puede desplazar el puntero a través de coordenadas es decir indicandole el punto exacto el eje x,y ya he consultado un poco y la **clase point** tiene varios metodos como : `translate()` `move()`  que se supone que servirían para desplazar el puntero hasta el momento no he tenido ningún resultado. ¿Alguien ya lo  a usado antes?

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para evitar respuestas como "Sí, lo he usado dame mis puntos".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con la clase `java.awt.Robot`. Tiene un método `mouseMove` muy interesante además de otros de utilidad para la automatización de pruebas.

Saludos.

Comment: Eso es amigo justo para esto lo necesito es una automatización pero no puedo darle click en aceptar ya que sale en una ventana emergente y no se deja inspeccionar, la idea seria llegar el puntero hasta la posición y ejecutar el click.

Comment: @PedroTriviño si te ayuda la respuesta no dudes en ponerle flecha arriba, si no, tal vez debas editar tu pregunta, de cualquier manera sería muy útil un [mcve]

Comment: Muchas gracias David me sirvio para mover el puntero, pero pasa algo y es que después me pone la pantalla en blanco ¿sabes por qué?

Comment: La verdad es que sin código es difícil sacar conclusiones. Tienes algún tipo de excepción que indique el origen del problema?